# I need help understanding an equivalent expression in Algebra?

Tags: calculus

I'm really confused about this math problem. I'm currently taking Calculus, but this problem seems to be like something basic in Algebra that I should understand.... Unfortunately, I don't remember what equivalent expression was used for this.

The problem is:

[Math problem picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjudA.png)

The main part I need help with is, how did:

$$\frac{(a - x)(a + x) + (a - x)}{a - x}$$

turn into:

$$\frac{(a - x)((a + x) + 1)} {a - x}$$

Where did the 1 come from?

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Putting $(a-x)$ in evidence. If you have $30$ oranges + $1$ orange, you have $(30+1)$ oranges. Similarly, if you have $(a+x)$ of $(a-x)$ plus $1$ of $(a-x)$, you have $(a+x+1)(a-x)$

Comment: $a(b+1)=ab+a$ by distributive property/ law whatever it is. And of course you can read the equality going the other way around $ab+a=a(b+1)$; after all it is an equality.

Comment: @randomgirl Thank you! I imagined that the "a-x" and "a+x" in the problem were "a" and "b" and it made sense! I have a full understanding now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(a-x)=d$. Then the equivalence of these expressions is just saying that $(a+x)d+d=d((a+x)+1)$ (for the numerator) so you're just factoring.

Answer (score 0):

Just take out a factor of $(a-x)$:
$$ (a-x)(a+x)+(a-x)1=(a-x)((a+x)+1)$$